# BeautifulSoup crawling cookies

Tags: python, drupal, cookies, web-crawler

I've been tasked with creating a cookie audit tool that crawls the entire website and gathers data on all cookies on the page and categorizes them according to whether they follow user data or not. I'm new to Python but I think this will be a great project for me, would beautifulsoup be a suitable tool for the job? We have tons of sites and are currently migrating to Drupal so it would have to be able to scan Polopoly CMS and Drupal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't need bs4 for this purpose because you only require info from cookies. (use bs4 only if finally you need to extract something from html code).

For the cookies stuff I would use python-request and its support to http sessions: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: It has to support Polopoly, Drupal and likely WordPress sites, do you think this would be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Urllib2 is for submitting http requests, BeautifulSoup is for parsing html. You'll definitely need a http request library, and you may need BeautifulSoup as well depending on what exactly you want to do.

`BeautifulSoup` is extremely easy to use and parses broken html well, so would be good for grabbing the links to any javascript on a page (even in cases where the html is malformed). You'll then need something else to parse the javascript to figure out whether it's interacting with the cookies.

To see what the cookie values are on the client-side just look at the http-request header or use `cookielib` (although I've personally not used this library).

For http requests, I recommend the `requests` library, looking at the http-request headers will be as simple as:

```
response = requests.get(url)
header   = response.headers
```

I suspect `requests` also has a shortcut for just accessing the `Set-Cookie` values of the header as well, but you'll need to look into that.

Comment: Thanks! Just starting this project now, the crawl will go through Drupal, WordPress and Polopoly sites so I assume they'll manage content differently hence looking at at BS. From the breakdown the audit will also have to support multi-threading but that's more on my end.

Comment: Good luck with the project, if one of these answers answered your question, could you accept it?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need `BeautifulSoup` for this. You could do this with `urllib2` for connection and `cookielib` for operations on cookies.